# Does it possible to deploying a none-web application on Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

plz tell me...
I want to deploy a pure java code like jar file, NOT web application, on Cloud Foundry.
is it possible or not?

Comment: Yes I think so. They call it standalone apps

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. This is called "Standalone apps" and is described here : http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/01/cloud-foundry-improves-support-for-background-processing/

Just choose that kind of framework when deploying. You'll need to provide the startup script for your app, ie the command that spawns java

Comment: Hello Ebottard, the mentioned blog link does not open. Could you please update it or share information directly?